# JSON Select option question?

Tags: json

I wrote somethinh like this,

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbase";

```
    $strOptions = "";

    if (!$q=mysql_query($sql)) {
        $strOptions = "<option>There was an error connecting to database</option>";
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($q)==0) {
        $strOptions = "<option>There are no news in database</option>";
    }else {
        $a=0;
        while ($redak=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
            $a=$a+1;
            $vvvv[$a]["id"]=$redak["id"];
            $vvvv[$a]["ssss"]=$redak["ssss"];
        }
    }
    for ($i=1; $i<=$a; $i++) {
        $strOptions = $strOptions. '<option value="'. $vvvv[$i]["id"] .'">'.$i.'.) - '.strip_tags($vvvv[$i]["ssss"]).'</option>';
    }


    echo '[{ "message": "3" },{ "message": "' . count($wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM dbase")) . '" },{ "message": "'.$strOptions .'"}]';`
```

I just cannot later parse json file,later I parse it on this way to fill select-option

```
$jq("#select-my").children().remove();
        $jq("#select-my").append(data[2].message);
```

I use jquery form pluing,everything work fine,except this,I cant parse data for select-option element.I try and with json_encode in php.Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your PHP right, your JSON ends up looking like this:

```
[{ "message": "3" },{ "message": "(count_goes_here)" },{ "message": "(options_go_here)"}]
```

The top level of a [JSON](http://json.org) string *must* be an anonymous object, not array ([details](http://json.org)). So this is valid:

```
{"test": ["one", "two", "three"]}
```

but the array on its own is not:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

To fix it, just wrap your array in an object:

```
{"values": [{ "message": "3" },{ "message": "(count_goes_here)" },{ "message": "(options_go_here)"}]}
```

...and then when you've deserialized the JSON string, use the `values` property of the resulting object to access the array.

Comment: Give me a second to try,sorry I'm new at jquery and json,tnx for answer